# setuptools, use package on local system instead of getting it from PyPI

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, setuptools, pypi, beeware

There is an open-source python package that I want to work on (toga-android). To test the code I write, I have to be able to build my own project that has said open-source package as a dependency. My project has to be built with setuptools, so I need setuptools to fulfill the dependency using my version of the package, and not get the package from PyPI.
The problem is that setuptools always gets the package from PyPI.

Whenever I build with setuptools I see:

> Collecting toga-android==0.3.0.dev8
>
> Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/92/fe/348a39e2e0bbcac2d3ed511dd2b62943b488e7dcb8097c437416caf1c179/toga_android-0.3.0.dev8-py3-none-any.whl

or

> Collecting toga-android==0.3.0.dev8
>
> Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/92/fe/348a39e2e0bbcac2d3ed511dd2b62943b488e7dcb8097c437416caf1c179/toga_android-0.3.0.dev8-py3-none-any.whl

Clearly it is getting the package from PyPI or using a cached version from it.

I have installed my version using `pip install -e .` , and that has no effect. I have also tried including the package's source in my project's directory with setup.py. Setuptools apparently includes this code because syntax errors there make the build fail, but it doesn't recognize that it can satisfy the dependency. It still gets the package from PyPI and any modules imported from the package are the PyPI versions.

How can I use of custom version of a package that is also in PyPI as a setuptools dependency?

Steps to reproduce:

1. pip install briefcase (using or not using virtualenv does not matter)
2. git clone https://github.com/pybee/toga.git
3. cd ~/toga/src/core; sudo pip install -e .
4. cd ~/toga/src/android/; sudo pip install -e .
5. cd ~/toga/examples/tutorial0
6. python setup.py android
7. The output will show that an older version of toga-android is downloaded even though it was already installed with pip.

Comment: What is the version of `toga-android` you have installed and what is the dependency version declared in setup script, do they match? Also, consider creating an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Yes they do match. Additionally, if the version number installed is updated past what is in PyPI, and setup.py is changed to match, the build fails and setuptools declares it couldn't satisfy the dependency.

Comment: Stop using `sudo pip install`, you're installing for the wrong user..

Comment: Sounds reasonable. pip list (no sudo) will still show it as installed. But, I guess the question becomes how do I deal with `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/toga_core-0.2.15.dist-info'`

Comment: By using `pip install --user`.  This is unrelated to your question, btw (you probably want to experiment with `--no-index` or `--no-deps` or something)

Comment: `setuptools` has nothing to do with it, it's `briefcase` defining own installation logic. The particular line you're experiencing difficulties with is [this one](https://github.com/pybee/briefcase/blob/d42e07656bdf5c58b8155011173f3ed106fe038c/briefcase/app.py#L281).